# How is goog.ui.ac.AutoComplete supposed to be used?

Tags: google-closure

[The source code](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/ui/ac/autocomplete.js) refers to [this demo](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/demos/autocomplete-basic.html), but I can't seem to get that to run directly. When I copy/paste that into my own project I end up with (more or less) this:

```html
<html>
  <head><script src="main.js" defer></script></head>
  <link href="autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <body></body>
</html>
```

```js
goog.module('Main');

const TagName = goog.require("goog.dom.TagName");
const {ArrayMatcher, AutoComplete, InputHandler, Renderer} = goog.require("goog.ui.ac");
const {createDom} = goog.require("goog.dom");

/**
 * The entry point.
 */
function Main() {
  console.log("Running");

  const inp = createDom(TagName.INPUT, {'type': "text"});
  document.body.appendChild(inp);

  // Copyed from https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/ui/ac/ac.js
  const matcher = new ArrayMatcher(["hello", "world"], true);
  const renderer = new Renderer(inp);
  const inputHandler = new InputHandler(null, null, false);

  const autoComplete = new AutoComplete(matcher, renderer, inputHandler);
  inputHandler.attachAutoComplete(autoComplete);
  inputHandler.attachInputs(inp);

  console.log("Finished", renderer.getElement());
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Main);
```

What that ends up doing is basically tab-completion: if I type `he<tab>` I get `hello`. But I don't get the expected list of potential completions popping up.

Digging around in the debugger, I can see it doing DOM manipulations and creating stuff that looks like it's *supposed* to be a list-of-option-element, but nothing is visible in the browser.

---

- Am I misusing something?
- Am I missing something? (E.g. some more CSS files I'm supposed to be using?)
- Am I using the wrong widget?
- Is the fact I need to do this as part of a Bazel build messing me up some how?

Comment: Looks like it might just not work anymore: https://github.com/google/closure-library/issues/1185#issuecomment-1472477618 :-(